# Почему вылетает NullPointerException при использовании do while?

Tags: java

Задача сохранить в файл все ссылки в указанном URL. Во время чтения через BufferedReader вылетает NullPointerException при использовании цикла `do while` в строке `if (buffer.indexOf ("<a ")> 0) }` ,а при использовании `for` все работает, хотя по идее оба цикла выполняют одно и то же. Подскажите почему так. Ранее без проблем использовал как один, так и другой цикл.

Вылетает:

```
  public static void getLinks(String link, String file) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
        String buffer = "";
        String text = "";

        do {
            buffer = input.readLine();

            if (buffer.indexOf("<a ") > 0) { // NullPointerException
                if (buffer.indexOf("</a") > 0) {
                    sb.append(buffer.substring(buffer.indexOf("<a "), buffer.indexOf("</a") + 4))
                            .append(System.lineSeparator());
                    text = "";
                } else {
                    text = buffer.substring(buffer.indexOf("<a "));
                }
            } else if (text.length() > 0) {
                if (buffer.indexOf("</a") > 0) {
                    sb.append(text).append(text + buffer.substring(1, buffer.indexOf("</a") + 4))
                            .append(System.lineSeparator());
                    text = "";
                } else {
                    text += buffer;
                }
            }
        } while (buffer != null);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    try (ObjectOutputStream links = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
        links.writeObject(sb.toString());
        System.out.println("File " + file + " was saved!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error save file!");
    }
}
```

Работает:

```
public static void getLinks(String link, String file) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
        String buffer = "";
        String text = "";

        for (; (buffer = input.readLine()) != null;) { // работает

            if (buffer.indexOf("<a ") > 0) {
                if (buffer.indexOf("</a") > 0) {
                    sb.append(buffer.substring(buffer.indexOf("<a "), buffer.indexOf("</a") + 4))
                            .append(System.lineSeparator());
                    text = "";
                } else {
                    text = buffer.substring(buffer.indexOf("<a "));
                }
            } else if (text.length() > 0) {
                if (buffer.indexOf("</a") > 0) {
                    sb.append(text).append(text + buffer.substring(1, buffer.indexOf("</a") + 4))
                            .append(System.lineSeparator());
                    text = "";
                } else {
                    text += buffer;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    try (ObjectOutputStream links = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
        links.writeObject(sb.toString());
        System.out.println("File " + file + " was saved!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error save file!");
    }
}
```

Comment: А в цикл то заходит во втором случае?

Comment: То же, что и в первом случае: `buffer = input.readLine()`, только оно встроено в условие цикла `for (; (buffer = input.readLine()) != null;)`

Comment: Я понимаю что проверка встроена, но в цикл то заходит или сразу выходит без единой итерации?

Comment: @temq а какое это имеет значение в контексте вопроса? В любом случае `do-while` здесь выглядит неуместно и требует доп. проверки на `null` в теле цикла.

Comment: @Regent это все понятно, я лишь хотел натолкнуть человека на мысль, что его код работает, но не так как нужно, т.к. очевидно, что ожидалось исполнение телка цикла хотя бы один раз, а не мгновенный выход из него.

Comment: @temq я, видимо, не понимаю вашу мысль. Да, суть `do-while` в том, что гарантированно выполняется хотя бы одна итерация, и в редких ситуациях это бывает полезно. Однако в представленном коде проблема не с потоком из 0 строк, для которого выполнение обязательной первой итерации всё сломает, а с потоком из любого числа строк, ибо при любом количестве строк всё кончится `NullPointerException`-ом. Так что либо вы наталкиваете автора на мысль не о той проблеме, либо я чего-то не понял.

Comment: `for(buffer = input.readLine(); buffer != null; buffer = input.readLine()){}`

Comment: @vp_arth условие проверки в этом случае выглядит простым, однако тут налицо дублирование кода.

Comment: @Regent, согласен, написал ответ с итератором.

Comment: @Regent я видимо не совсем до конца понял вопрос, и зацепился за то, что уже первая попытка приводила к ошибке и хотел навести на мысль, что в первом случае работа с буфером происходит до проверки, тогда как во втором сначала идет проверка, а потом уже дальнейшая работа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш `do-while` работает не так же, как `for`: в `for` перед каждой итерацией проверяется, что считанный `buffer` не равен `null`. В `do-while` же эта проверка происходит после того, как `buffer` уже был использован, и, по сути, поэтому проверка лишена смысла, так как если `buffer` равен `null`, то об этом станет известно уже в строке `if (buffer.indexOf("<a ") > 0)` про проброшенному `NullPointerException`, и до `while` дело не дойдёт.

Имеет смысл `do-while` заменить на `while`:

```
while ((buffer = input.readLine()) != null)
```

---

При использовании Java 8 можно пройтись по всем строкам с использованием for-each.

Например, так:

```
Stream<String> stream = input.lines();
for (String buffer : (Iterable<String>)stream::iterator) { ... }
```

Или хотя бы так:

```
for (String buffer : input.lines().collect(Collectors.toList())) { ... }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я так понимаю `while (buffer != null) { buffer = input.readLine();` тоже не подходит. Можно ли тогда как-нибудь вынести операцию `buffer = input.readLine()` за пределы `while ()`, т.е. перенести в тело цикла?

Comment: @Sergey да, тоже не подходит. Вынести в тело цикла можно, но зачем это делать?

Comment: Хочу понимать принцип как это можно сделать и провести аналогии с тем, как это делал ранее, потому что ранее почему-то такой проблемы с `do-while` не возникало. Может получиться, что раньше все время использовал его неправильно.

Comment: @Sergey можно сделать [таким образом](https://jsfiddle.net/c1wfu4ae/). Но, на мой взгляд, этот код выглядит куда хуже случая, при котором условие выхода из цикла находится в самом `while`.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ - очень помогли! Да, код выглядит получше с условием внутри `while`. Нужно было, чтобы пазл в голове сложился.

Answer (score 2):

Построчное чтение файла предполагает чтение строки и проверку на каждой итерации:

```
while (true) {
  buffer = input.readLine();
  if (buffer == null) break;
  // ...
}
```

Или:

```
do {
  buffer = input.readLine();
  // buffer может быть null здесь, поэтому обязательна проверка:
  if (buffer == null) break;
  // ...
} while (buffer != null); // Из-за проверки выше, проверка здесь не имеет смысла. Выражение всегда true
```

Как верно заметил @Regent, этот код также можно записать как:

```
while ((buffer = input.readLine()) != null) {}
```

Хотя на самом деле, ваш цикл `for` является полным ему аналогом - `for(;cond;);` эквивалентен `while(cond);`

Однако многие styleguides прямо запрещают использование оператора присваивания в условиях.

Если чтение первой строки считать инициализацией цикла, то можно записать этот код как:

```
for(buffer = input.readLine(); buffer != null; buffer = input.readLine()){
  // ...
}
```

Однако здесь, очевидно, налицо дублирование кода.

---

В Java, когда нам нужно перебрать элементы некоторой коллекции(например, строк в файле) мы описываем итератор.
Давайте попробуем:

```
public class BufferedReaderIterator implements Iterable<String> {
    private BufferedReader input;
    public BufferedReaderIterator(BufferedReader input) {
      this.input = input;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                try {
                    input.mark(1);
                    if (input.read() < 0) return false;
                    input.reset();
                    return true;
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {return false; }
            }
            @Override
            public String next() {
                try { return input.readLine(); } 
                catch (IOException e) {return null; }
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
        };
    }
```

И вот как теперь будет выглядеть первоначальный цикл:

```
for(String buffer: new BufferedReaderIterator(input)){
  // ...
}
```

Мы избавились и от дублирования, и от присваивания.

---

В качестве альтернативы можно воспользоваться готовым решением, например:  [org.apache.commons.io.LineIterator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html).
Правда с ним придётся обрабатывать исключения.

Comment: Жаль что за компактный `for` придётся заплатить целым доп. классом. Но если не использовать Java 8 и решения наподобие того, которое мне навеял ваш ответ, то, наверно, короче и не получится

Comment: @Regent, важно понимать, что решение с `.lines().collect` хоть и выглядит похоже, является принципиально иным. Оно читает весь файл до первой итерации, что вполне приемлемо для небольших файлов.

Comment: Безусловно. Под аналогией я подразумевал использование for-each. Исправлю описание в ответе во избежание недоразумений.

Comment: Спасибо за участие. `iterator`, конечно же, для такой задачи вряд ли буду использовать. Но вы тут предусмотрели, что называется, все возможные варианты.